# ssi on nginx, using variables and conditionals

Tags: nginx, server-side-includes

I'm using nginx to server up my static pages. To make the menu dynamically change the `class="active"` on the respective page, I'm trying to use SSI variables. So I have this on the page itself:

```
<!--#set var="pageOn" value="floorCare" -->
```

and then a bit further down:

```
<!--#include virtual="./includes/header.html" -->
```

Inside the header.html file, I have:

```
foo: <!--# if expr="(${pageOn} = floorCare" -->class="active"<!--# endif -->
```

My understanding (from what I've read up on today), is that this should work. Instead, I get:

> foo: [an error occurred while processing the
>   directive]class="active"[an error occurred while processing the
>   directive]

I know SSI itself is working (as the header/footer is included fine otherwise)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an extra bracket in `expr=` value.

It should be: `expr="${pageOn} = floorCare"` or `expr="$pageOn = floorCare"`, parentheses are not an allowed syntax outside of a string.